# How do I create a custom calendar using the Custom Content Query Webpart?

Tags: content-query-web-part

I currently have two sites right now, a Parent Team Site and a sub team Site. I am trying to use the content query webpart to pull the Calendar entries from the sub team Site into the Parent Team Site.

http://blog.greenbrain.de/2013/08/adding-calendar-icon-to-content-query.html

I am trying to use that tutorial to create a custom template for Calendar, whenever I load the template Calendar in my Content Query Webpart, it bricks and outputs:

Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

Correlation ID:7d037b9c-7d4e-1045-1630-4fa42e1de82d

Any help would be very appreciated - I am trying to figure this out myself but I would appreciate any sort of pointers as to how to proceed. If there is an easier way to pull up calendar entries from the other site and display it in a "consolidated" calendar, let me know!

Comment: Have you tried calendar overlays instead of a CQWP?

Answer (score 0):

Check the XSLT file for errors. A single little mistake can take down the entire CQWP.

Comment: Do you have any good method for doing this?